# Apply CSS only on decimals for Woocmmerce

Tags: css, woocommerce, styles, wpml

I'm trying to find a function that will make the decimal postions in the Woocommerce prices to have their own CSS class, so i can apply a different style than the one for the the non decimal part of the price. I have multi-lingual and multi-currency website.

I found a code that does what I'm looking for but it was coded in a way that will replace the currency symbol for the brazilian symbol, and because i don't know how to code myself, i could not amend the code to apply to my needs.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `<span>` to the decimals and create a class just for them :

HTML :

```
<div name="price">
    &#36; 99.<span class="decimals">99<span>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.decimals {
    /* The style you want for the decimals goes here */
}
```

Comment: Hi Matheus, I cant add a span to decimals, as the prices in woocommerce is not something you can or at least i don't know how, add css that way. Is not like a html plain text that i can amend... i don't know if that makes sense.

Comment: Go to your files in `wp-content` and browse your way into the `templates` folded. The whole path is : `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/`. There you will have your global folder and cart folder, which there's probably .PHP files that you can edit and code the **HTML** section inside. You then, just find the related .CSS file to the cart or global and apply the style to the class created on the `<span>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `formatted_woocommerce_price` filter. Check code example. You can change `sub` to any HTML element you want with your specific class.

```
add_filter( 'formatted_woocommerce_price', 'style_decimal_price', 10, 5 );
function style_decimal_price( $formatted_price, $price, $decimal_places, $decimal_separator, $thousand_separator ) {

    $unit    = number_format( intval( $price ), 0, $decimal_separator, $thousand_separator );
    $decimal = sprintf( '%02d', ( $price - intval( $price ) ) * 100 );

    return $unit . '<sub class="custom-decimal">' . $decimal_separator. $decimal . '</sub>';
}
```